# How do you set the command-line arguments in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having trouble setting the command-line arguments in Eclipse.

I've searched around the Internet but can't find anything that helps people with invisible textboxes. I even tried pressing the help button and nothing came up.

How does one set the command-line arguments in Eclipse for a Java project?

[Screenshot of Eclipse http://static.zooomr.com/images/8978910_d91c113b07.jpg](http://static.zooomr.com/images/8978910_d91c113b07.jpg)

Edit:
I've tried blowing away Eclipse and reinstalling to no avail.

I also scanned for JREs again and switched to using the JDK instead of the JRE. This did not help matters.

Comment: Reinstall eclipse. I'm running under win7, and I see the textboxes.

Comment: That's the correct dialog. I see textboxes. Do you have the latest version? Any unusual plugins?

Comment: I'm using a fresh install of Eclipse Galileo.

Comment: I take it you've tried resizing that window to no avail?

Comment: @Jack We have a winner! I take it that you have also experienced high DPI problems. :)

Comment: Nope, I just tried resizing the window (on my Mac) after posting that question, to see if it'll cause the text boxes to disappear (it did, even on the Mac). Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resizing the window to make the text boxes appear.

I tried it on my Mac and if you make the window small enough the text boxes get obscured.

Comment: Don't fret about it. I have no problem with giving you the well-earned reputation points. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the main class and java runtime version first to see the text boxes. Then put the args in the "Program arguments" textbox.