# Make java application ask for arguments before run

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

I want my Java application to ask for specific arguments (like name and email) before running in Eclipse. How can I make it do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "running in eclipse"?

Comment: @Michael he is using eclipse editor. :)

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt, i have a small java app used for development, and i want before running it in eclipse to ask for some arguments before main method gets executed, got it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260481/passing-system-commands-along-with-command-line-arguments-in-eclipse check this and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436720/how-do-you-set-the-command-line-arguments-in-eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not part of the Java code - it's part of the run configuration.

Go to the Run drop down (the down-arrow next to the run button), select Run Configurations, and then find your program and select it.

Go to the Arguments tab, and then in the Program Arguments click on "Variables..." to get a list of possible variables for Eclipse to use. For example:

```
${string_prompt:Foo}
```

That will prompt the user for a value for "Foo" when you then run that configuration.

Comment: can i change the message that appears, `please input a value for` ?

Comment: @fresh_dev: Not that I'm aware of, but look through the different placeholders available to see if one fits. This is really just meant to be a quick helper - if you want something more substantial, you should put it in your code instead.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the run configuration of the class you want to run, go to the *Arguments* tab, click the *Variables...* button under the *Program arguments* text box, and select one of the `*prompt` variables. Do that for each argument.

Answer (score 0):

While this approach would **not** technically ask the user for input **before** the java application starts running, it could accomplish basically the same thing:

You could use an easy-to-use SWING class, JOptionPane. This way, the input prompts would be a part of the application, but if you put them at the very beginning of the main() method, it have roughly the same effect as prompting before the application starts. Using this, you'd add something like the following to your source code, at the very beginning:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter name:");
String email = JOptionPane.showInoputDialog("Please enter email:");
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) is a reference to how the JOptionPane class works.

Using this, a popup box in which the user can enter text will appear when the application is started.